# Multivariate analysis - creating a classification index

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have the following problem I would like to tackle, I thought it would be useful to get some help for determining the best possible workflow.

I have data for some 200 biological observations. 1 of the measured parameters gives a pretty accurate description of the property I would like to evaluate.
4 other parameters I expect to give some information on this property, but are clearly also influenced by a number of other factors.

I would like to create an index (based on the observations I have) to classify future observations, where only the last 4 parameters will be measured.

(Additionally: for one of these parameters a number of observations is below the detection limit. What is the best way to go about this? Replace these values by DL/2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a regression problem: You can use 4 "other" parameters as independent variables to predict 1 "pretty accurate" one as the dependent variable. The choice of regression method will depend on what you want to do with your index. Should it be easy to calculate the index without a computer? Then linear regression might be a good place to start.